# How to use std::getline with Glib::ustring

Tags: c++, readline, glib

I am trying to read the contents of a text file into `Glib::ustring`s. As i understand for the [gtkmm-list at gnome.org](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2008-May/msg00195.html) I should read a line into an `std::string` and only then do the conversion. It works when the text is in ASCII, but fails when given something else.

Example code is:

```
#include <glibmm/ustring.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("testfile");
    while(fin)
    {
        Glib::ustring str;
        {
            std::string s;
            std::getline(fin, s);
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
            str.assign(s);
        }
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the file contents (saved as UTF8) are

```
hello
привет
```

The first line is printed twice, meaning that `ustring` is getting constructed just fine, but the second one comes out fine as `std::string`, but then `Glib::ConvertError` gets thrown. The code of the error is `ILLEGAL_SEQUENCE`.

I have double checked and the file is as follows:

```
 00000000:  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a d0 bf  d1 80 d0 b8 d0 b2 d0 b5  hello...........
 00000010:  d1 82 0a -- -- -- -- --  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ...-------------
```

It does appear to be UTF-8. For example d1 82 are 11010001 10000010, which would make it the character 10001000010 in binary or U+0442, in other words Cyrillic 'т'. I have displayed every character or a read `std::string` and have confirmed that the file was read correctly.

Comment: OT: `while (fin)` is the same as `while (fin.good())` which is just as bad as [`while (!fin.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: [The class `Glib::ConvertError`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ConvertError.html) has a public member function `code()` that returns a value of the enum type `Glib::ConvertError::Code`, which may help to identify the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer actually was not in the reading, but in the output. After changing it to

```
std::cout << str.raw() << std::endl;
```

Everything worked like a charm.